# What is the callback or return function in android studio using java?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, mobile

Respect my post Im a newbie :) thank you for understanding
sorry for my grammar

This program is to choose from gallery permission and send to second activity. the
permission is allowed is okay it will send it to the second activity...but when i clicked "oks" in the first popup permission and when i "dont allow files access the device" it   will run and when i click button "pick " it will stay to and main activity when i click the button "pick"

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void buttonGalleryOpen(View view)
{
Intent intent = new Intent(this, gallery_view.class);
startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="camera sample"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/textview1"
android:layout_marginTop="3dp">

<Button
android:id="@+id/button_pick"
android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:onClick="buttonGalleryOpen"
android:text="pick" />


</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gallery_view.java

```
public class gallery_view extends AppCompatActivity {
private int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_view);

if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(gallery_view.this, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, 
android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
//noinspection deprecation
startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
} else {

requestStoragePermission();
}

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {

Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageviewfromgallery);
imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);

} else {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);
}
}


private void requestStoragePermission() {

if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, 
Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setTitle("Permission needed")
.setMessage("This permission is needed because of this and that")
.setPositiveButton("oks", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(gallery_view.this, new 
String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);

}
})
.setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
dialog.dismiss();
}
})
.create().show();
    } else {

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

    }
 }

}
```

activity_gallery_view.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/relative_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="camera sample"
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
android:layout_below="@id/relative_1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageviewfromgallery"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So, I suppose, in case of unsuccess permission, you need return to previous screen(activity)? Is that what you ask for?

Comment: Yes sir. Thats what im trying to say. Thank you.

Comment: Write finish() before dialog.dismiss()

Comment: It work on the cancel button. But if i "dont allow files" it will redirected to the 1st activity and whenever i clicked the button it will loop forever in the first activity.

Comment: If i dont allow the files to be access. It be redirected to the first activity and it will ask permission again.

Comment: Ok, first of all, read official documentation about permissions to deeply understand how does it work https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java, also try to send user to app settings to change permission in app settings

Answer (score 0):

Check official documentation here https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java
Also, after user disabled permission dialog,try to send user to app settings to enable it manually.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS); Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null); intent.setData(uri); startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
```